# How to update table from server-side postgresql C language extension?

Tags: c, postgresql

There is good documentation here (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/xfunc-c.html), but I didn't find a way to read/modify/delete data from existing table by tablename and columns name from C extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is [SPI](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/spi.html).

P. S. Do you actually use 8.3? Use the latest (9.4) if you're not restricted somehow.